# Coding a simple game having some troubles

Tags: javascript, html

I have a following code (if input 'u' - works fine, but others not working properly).
If you have problems like 'cannot read property of null' - it's problem with snippet posting, on my browser-side I don't have problems like this.
Main problem - for example - if you enter 5 and 'd' then - it says 'you cant step here'. But you can! It seems like an IF statement set nice.

```js
window.onload = function core () {
 let platform = document.createElement('div');
 platform.setAttribute('id','platform');
 document.body.appendChild(platform);
 let count = 0;
 for (let i=1; i<101; i++) {
  let grid = document.createElement('button');
  grid.setAttribute('id',i);
  grid.setAttribute('class','eachGridBlock');
  document.getElementById('platform').appendChild(grid);
  count++;
  if (count === 10) {
   let newLine = document.createElement('br');
   document.getElementById('platform').appendChild(newLine);
   count = 0;
  };
 };
 let defaultPosition = 1;
 document.getElementById(defaultPosition).setAttribute('class','focusedBlock');
 let nowPosition = prompt('where am I? (number)');
 let userInput = prompt('where to go? (up, down, left, right)');
 document.getElementById(defaultPosition).setAttribute('class','eachGridBlock');
 document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class','focusedBlock');
 if (userInput === 'd') {
  if (nowPosition >= 91) {
   alert('you cant step here');
  } else {
   let nextPosition = nowPosition + 10;
   document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class','eachGridBlock');
   document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class','focusedBlock');
  };
 };
 if (userInput === 'u') {
  if (nowPosition <= 10) {
   alert('you cant step here');
  } else {
   let nextPosition = nowPosition - 10;
   document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class','eachGridBlock');
   document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class','focusedBlock');
  };
 };
 if (userInput === 'l') {
  if (nowPosition === 1 || nowPosition === 11 || nowPosition === 21 || nowPosition === 31 || nowPosition === 41 || nowPosition === 51 || nowPosition === 61 || nowPosition === 71 || nowPosition === 81 || nowPosition === 91) {
   alert('you cant step here');
  } else {
   let nextPosition = nowPosition - 1;
   document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class','eachGridBlock');
   document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class','focusedBlock');
  };
 };
 if (userInput === 'r') {
  if (nowPosition === 10 || nowPosition === 20 || nowPosition === 30 || nowPosition === 40 || nowPosition === 50 || nowPosition === 60 || nowPosition === 70 || nowPosition === 80 || nowPosition === 90 || nowPosition === 100) {
   alert('you cant step here');
  } else {
   let nextPosition = nowPosition + 1;
   document.getElementById(nowPosition).setAttribute('class','eachGridBlock');
   document.getElementById(nextPosition).setAttribute('class','focusedBlock');
  };
 };
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  #plarform {
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: #222222;
  }
  .eachGridBlock {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #000044;
   border: 0;
  }
  .focusedBlock {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #9900ff;
   border: 0;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./core.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have now troubles with 'Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
    at core'. Why?(

Comment: Your elements all have *string* ID values in the HTML, but you treat them as integers in the JavaScript side (`document.getElementById(nowPosition)`). You'll need to get turn `nowPosition` and `nextPosition` to a string value if you're going to use them in `.getElementById()`.

Comment: But why *integer* with 'u' (up) works fine?

Comment: Okay, I did a *parseInt()* and now it works fine. Thanks to Obsidian Age ;)